# open one dropdown at a time while using ngHide/ngShow angular directives

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have a simple dropdown menu that I want to tweak a little. I need help with animating the dropdown so it's scaling down when it opens. But that is not my biggest concern. What I really need help with is opening only one dropdown at a time. So if I open one and another one had already been previously opened, it should close.

I'm using Angular-Material, so I am looking for an Angular Controller or directive solution please, one that uses ngHide/ngShow directives perhaps? Not sure about that part.

This is my HTML

```
    <md-list ng-click="menuIsOpen = !menuIsOpen" layout="row" layout-padding="" class="layout-row" layout-align="start center" flex> 
        <span class="title flex" flex=""> Menu Item</span>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
    </md-list>
    <div class="sub-menu">
        <ul ng-init="menuIsOpen= false" ng-show="menuIsOpen">
            <md-menu-item ng-repeat="item in data">
                <md-button>
                    <div layout="row" flex="">
                        <a ui-sref="{{item.link}}">
                            <p flex=""><i class="fa fa-{{item.icon}}"></i> {{item.title}}</p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </md-button>
            </md-menu-item>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <md-list ng-click="menu2IsOpen = !menu2IsOpen" layout="row" layout-padding="" class="layout-row" layout-align="start center" flex> 
        <span class="title flex" flex=""> Menu Item 2</span>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
    </md-list>
    <div class="sub-menu">
        <ul ng-init="menu2IsOpen= false" ng-show="menu2IsOpen">
            <md-menu-item ng-repeat="item in data">
                <md-button>
                    <div layout="row" flex="">
                        <a ui-sref="{{item.link}}">
                            <p flex=""><i class="fa fa-{{item.icon}}"></i> {{item.title}}</p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </md-button>
            </md-menu-item>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I have a [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/pRNLwo) you can checkout. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why can't you use a simple ng-if condition to validate and close one when the other is opened. On click of one dropdown you can set the value for the 2nd dropdown to false and viceversa. Then use the values in your ng-if or ng-show

Comment: @CrazyMac that does sound good! Care to post an answer with an example? If you don't mind. I'll appreciate it

Comment: The code posted by Jenny should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ng-click`, set variable `menuIsOpen` to `ng-click="menuIsOpen = 1"` and as `ng-show="menuIsOpen === 1 "` Do the same thing with other menus.

**Example**

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <button ng-click="menuIsOpen = 1">About Page</button>
  <button ng-click="menuIsOpen = 2">Help page</button>
  <button ng-click="menuIsOpen = 3">Info Page</button>
  <button ng-click="menuIsOpen = 4">Refrence page</button>

  <div class="form-group" ng-show="menuIsOpen===1">
    <p>About page</p>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group" ng-show="menuIsOpen===2">
    <p>Help page</p>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group" ng-show="menuIsOpen===3">
    <p>Info</p>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group" ng-show="menuIsOpen===4">
    <p>Refrence</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
  <div ng-controller="ListBottomSheetCtrl" class="md-padding bottomSheetdemoBasicUsage" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
        <div class="cnt">
            <md-list ng-click="menuIsOpen = 1" layout="row" layout-padding="" class="layout-row" layout-align="start center" flex> 
                <span class="title flex" flex=""> Menu Item</span>
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
            </md-list>
            <div class="sub-menu">
                <ul ng-init="menuIsOpen= false" ng-show="menuIsOpen === 1 ">
                    <md-menu-item ng-repeat="item in data">
                        <md-button>
                            <div layout="row" flex="">
                                <a ui-sref="{{item.link}}">
                                    <p flex=""><i class="fa fa-{{item.icon}}"></i> {{item.title}}</p>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </md-button>
                    </md-menu-item>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <md-list ng-click="menuIsOpen = 2" layout="row" layout-padding="" class="layout-row" layout-align="start center" flex> 
                <span class="title flex" flex=""> Menu Item 2</span>
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
            </md-list>
            <div class="sub-menu">
                <ul ng-init="menu2IsOpen= false" ng-show="menuIsOpen === 2 ">
                    <md-menu-item ng-repeat="item in data">
                        <md-button>
                            <div layout="row" flex="">
                                <a ui-sref="{{item.link}}">
                                    <p flex=""><i class="fa fa-{{item.icon}}"></i> {{item.title}}</p>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </md-button>
                    </md-menu-item>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved try following:

```
<div ng-controller="ListBottomSheetCtrl" class="md-padding bottomSheetdemoBasicUsage" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
<div class="cnt" ng-init="menuIsOpen= false; menu2IsOpen= false">
    <md-list ng-click="menuIsOpen = !menuIsOpen; menu2IsOpen = false" layout="row" layout-padding="" class="layout-row" layout-align="start center" flex> 
        <span class="title flex" flex=""> Menu Item</span>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
    </md-list>
    <div class="sub-menu">
        <ul ng-show="menuIsOpen">
            <md-menu-item ng-repeat="item in data">
                <md-button>
                    <div layout="row" flex="">
                        <a ui-sref="{{item.link}}">
                            <p flex=""><i class="fa fa-{{item.icon}}"></i> {{item.title}}</p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </md-button>
            </md-menu-item>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <md-list ng-click="menu2IsOpen = !menu2IsOpen; menuIsOpen = false" layout="row" layout-padding="" class="layout-row" layout-align="start center" flex> 
        <span class="title flex" flex=""> Menu Item 2</span>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
    </md-list>
    <div class="sub-menu">
        <ul  ng-show="menu2IsOpen">
            <md-menu-item ng-repeat="item in data">
                <md-button>
                    <div layout="row" flex="">
                        <a ui-sref="{{item.link}}">
                            <p flex=""><i class="fa fa-{{item.icon}}"></i> {{item.title}}</p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </md-button>
            </md-menu-item>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VPmgJp)